# A Lemma about connectedness

Tags: general-topology

Here is the Lemma and its proof :
[image]

I confused about 2 parts: first, the interval $[0,1]$ is a closed subset of the real numbers under the usual topology, but I guess when we think of this interval as a subset of itself, then it is an open subset of itself under the subspace topology on $[0,1]$. Right? Second, it is concluded that $z\in[0,1]$ by the fact that $[0,1]$ is closed. I don't get how it is followed by being closed. Actually, the whole proof seems a little bit confusing for me.

Comment: Yes as to first question. As to second, $z$ is the supremum of a subset of $[0,1]$. You can realize $z$ as a limit of a convergent sequence of elements of $[0,1]$ (e.g. given $n$, you can choose $\xi_n \in [0,1]$ such that $\xi_n > z - 1/n$, by the definition of $z$ as the supremum. That sequence will converge to $z$). So $[0,1]$ being closed lets you know that $z$ is in $[0,1]$ too.

Comment: @leslietownes You don’t really need sequences, it’s enough to see that the supremum of set is an adherent point in the order topology.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma trust me, I need sequences. :)